# Table 'fthdc_civi.civicrm_translation' doesn't exist

Tags: upgrade, duplicate-contacts, translation

This is likely an error that has come about as part of an upgrade. We went from CiviCRM 5.31 to 5.44 about a month ago and everything appeared to go well with the incremental database updates, etc.

However, when merging contacts in Civi, we now get a traceback with the following error:

`[nativecode=1146 ** Table 'fthdc_civi.civicrm_translation' doesn't exist]`

I won't paste the whole trace, but the start of the SQL query is:

`(SELECT 'civicrm_translation' as civicrm_table, 'entity_id' as field_name FROM civicrm_translation WHERE entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT ...`

Checking the database, it's true that the *civicrm_translation* table doesn't appear to exist.

Questions are:

1. When did the *civicrm_translation* table appear in Civi?
2. Is this something that should have been created in the upgrade process?
3. Is there anything that I can do to create this table and the necessary data in order to make merging contacts start working again?

Also, is this a bug that needs reporting?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the upgrade didn't fully work. It gets created as part of 5.39: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/bbc91a6b38e98b488867a3438d0ac0ee3f4f03c6/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/5.39.alpha1.mysql.tpl#L3

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `civicrm_translation` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique String ID',
  `entity_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Table where referenced item is stored',
  `entity_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Field where referenced item is stored',
  `entity_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of the relevant entity.',
  `language` varchar(5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Relevant language',
  `status_id` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Specify whether the string is active, draft, etc',
  `string` longtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Translated string',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `index_entity_lang`(entity_id, entity_table, language)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: Thank you thank you! Ran the SQL and tried merging a contact - seems to be working again now.

Comment: It would be worth checking other updates around that one to see if just that one failed or if a larger selection on updates were not done.  You seem to have fixed the immediate error but you may encounter future weirdness if other updates were missed.